# Angular binding error

Tags: angularjs, binding

I have a curious error on my angular app.

I have a controller where I declare some variables. If I am going to write them in the html it works as expected. But if I try to change them, eg in a input-box nothing happens.

Even when I try to call a function from a button or something nothing happens.
The code below is a simplified version of my controller.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'SomeServices',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, someServices) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.myVar = "foobar";
        $scope.myFunction = function() {
           // it never gets here
        }

        $scope.$watch("myVar", function() {
           // it even never gets here
        });
    }]);
```

My HTML

```
<!-- change this and the watcher will not doing anything -->
<!-- the value will bee foobar, but after that nothing happens -->
<input type="text" ng-model="myVar" /> 
<button ng-click="myFunction()">click here and nothing will happen</button>
```

If I tried it in codepen it works normaly.
Has anyone even got such a behaviour?

Comment: as i wrote - the error is that nothing happens. it like the binding is not working. i will figure it out a bit more. wait a second

Comment: Show your html please,full html please.

Comment: okay. i have edited the entry.

Comment: you have nothing entered in that function, paste this in myfunction ( ) $scope.myVar = "foobar"; Or what you want on clicking button exactly??

Comment: Is the input field getting prefilled?

Comment: the input field is getting correctly prefilled. @praveen in the real function there is some code. but it never gets there.

Comment: Do you bootstrap your module and controller?

Comment: @harmoniemand  use $scope as parameter in myFunction()

Comment: If you can't tell by the questions, there really isn't enough here to go off of. You will probably be better helped if you create a complete example in the question that shows the error you are getting.

Comment: I found the issue. It was tooo stupid. because of broccoli all my js-files where included twice. and I watched the wrong one. :(

Comment: you are breaking the all important rule in angular of always using an object in `ng-model`

Comment: why should i not use a string? ngModel is (afaik) not able to monitor complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem why it should not work, may be this is more simplified demonstration,

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = "foobar";
  $scope.myFunction = function() {
    console.log($scope.myVar + ' myFunction called')
  }

  $scope.$watch("myVar", function() {
    console.log($scope.myVar + ' value changed')
  });
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9">
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myVar" />
  <button ng-click="myFunction()">click here and nothing will happen</button>
</div>
```

Open developer tool to see logs.

Elaborate more if you are facing some other problem.